# write query in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is what I'm trying to retrieve: "Find the names of faculty members who teach in every room in which some class is taught"

My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE FACULTY (
  fid NUMERIC(6) NOT NULL,
  fname VARCHAR(20),
  dept VARCHAR(5),
  PRIMARY KEY (fid),
  FOREIGN KEY (fid)
  references STUDENT (sid)
 );
CREATE TABLE CLASS(
  cnum VARCHAR(6),
  meets_at TIME,
  room VARCHAR(6),
  fid NUMERIC(6) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (cnum),
  FOREIGN KEY (fid)
  references FACULTY (fid)     
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should google for the keyword "LEFT JOIN"